# How to change build system information path on Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I got  those 4 errors when I open my Xcode project.

***/Users/khcw1007/Manao-iOS/manao/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-manao/Pods-manao.debug.xcconfig***

I've 2 'Pods' in the path of xcode but in reality I've only one, I think that's my error come from here. Where can I edit the path to fix it ? I can't build my project in Swift.

[image]

Comment: is there is someone who already got this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed. I just uninstall and install Xcode again.